# Can we containerize an electron app using docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, electron

Currently, I have developed a desktop application using electron JS, and I am using electron-store to save user preference. And these prefernce are being saved in a `config.json` file inside the `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/<applicationName>/config.json`

I wonder if I have containerized my electron app using docker:

- Would I face any issues related to storage or anything else?
- Would I be able to run the app normally?
- Would I be able to run the GUI of the electron app?

Comment: May I raise the question about why you would dockerize your electron application? What are the pros of doing that?

Comment: My end goal is to not let people install node, npm and electron packages on their local system. They can use the docker image to develop this application. And I don't know maybe users can use the app without installing it using executable file. Please if you find any issues with what I am planning to do tell me.

Comment: For development purposes, you might want to check this: https://trigodev.com/blog/develop-electron-in-docker and for a "release" strategy, you can check this article: https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110 . To summarize: you can use docker to create develop an electron application in docker, although I personally would not, and yes, you technically can use docker to execute applications in a container, although once again I personally would not :)

Comment: Your end users would have to install Docker to run the application; running things in Docker requires root-equivalent permissions; the application couldn't access the user's home directory; and your end users wound have to do finicky Linux-specific setup to be able to see the GUI.  I don't think it's a good match.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your comment, sorry but I am new to docker, could you please illustrate more what do you mean by root-equivalent permissions? and do you mean by "the application couldn't access the user's home directory" that the user can't browser a location to store some data in his local machine?(if we are supposing that we were able to display the GUI). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AliOz I strongly recommend you to learn Docker first, because the core point of wrapping electron in docker is correctly understanding what electron needs to be able to work with Docker and what can be exposed to Docker. It's not trivial, take your time to study and understand Docker first. My 5 cents about it is that I would arguably accept that docker is used to develop on an electron application (although that's borderline), but imho a deployed application is already ready-to-use for all the operating systems, hence docker is just overkill in that case specifically.

Comment: On the one hand, a container can't access host files at all without a `docker run -v` option.  On the other, you can use that option to access any file at all on the host with unrestricted permissions; on Linux there are some easy one-liners to for example disable the root password, which are possible if you can run any `docker` command at all.